# How to make ellipse circle and resizable keeping its shape?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-10

[image]

I have got a Grid, and I want to make a templet a button look like a circle in one of the cells.

I've managed to make it placing it in Canvas but my Circle doesn't resize with the grid. When I used Vertical and Horizontal Alignment Stretch it doesn't work ether. 
The question is: How to make a circle in XAML, in one of the cells of the Grid to be resizable keeping it circle shape while I'm resize the window?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you, this code works fine:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Height="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

The eclipse mantains the shape and it is resize depending on the grid.

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. I've pasted it in and nothing. The ellipse(circle) does not show up:(

Comment: Of course, you need fill by any color. Add Fill="Red" for example.

Comment: I know , I did it. I put a screenshot to prove it.